# How to return multiple rows in Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, rows

I am new to Nhibernate. I want to retrieve collection of records against an entity. For example to retrieve a single record I have used the following statement:

resultObject=session.Get(id);

This above statement would retrieve a single record based on the 
'id" I provide.

But I want to retrieve multiple rows from a table the way we retrieve from the following sql statement: 
Select * from Student

How can I do this using Nhibernate? Please guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Criteria API](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-criteria)

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Student));
criteria.List<Student>();
```

Using [HQL](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql)

```
IQuery nhQuery = session.CreateQuery("FROM Student");
nhQuery.List<Student>()
```